# Ndiswrapper problems

Tags: wireless, system-installation

After I've installed Windows Wireless Drivers (ndiswrapper) I can't find them anywhere inside my computer but it says it's installed.

How do I proceed from here?.

Comment: Could you give a bit more information, please?  What exact WiFi card do you need drivers for, what version of Ubuntu are you running, ...  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you also installed the graphical front end, ndisgtk, then ndiswrapper is a command line only package. To see its options, open a terminal and run:

```
ndiswrapper --help
```

As in any command that will change your system, to install or erase a driver, prepend the command with 'sudo':

```
sudo ndiswrapper -i some_driver.inf
```

If you are having trouble, edit your question to include your details and we'll propose an answer.

Comment: Hye, thanks I have it working, how do I switch it to solved?

Comment: Glad it's working. See here for how to accept my answer: http://askubuntu.com/tour Thanks!